# Change MySQL database name in SQL file

Tags: mysql

I have a 2GB mysql backup file that has several databases in it and would like to change the name for one of the databases. What approaches  can I use to tackle this issue ? I have used sed but it ends up making changes where it should not.

```
sed 's/CREATE DATABASE \/*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*\/ `mydb`/`mydb2`/g' all_databases.sql > out.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to complicate it?

```
1). vi the backup.sql file. 

2). /mydb -> find for line 'mydb'

3). For sure the first two line will be this.



 CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mydb` ;
    use `mydb`;

4). Just change mydb from both the lines to mydb2 and save the file
and import it.
```

Comment: Well, I had to really think about this one. If the DB Server has 32G of RAM, `free -m` shows you have enough RAM free, and you run `vi all_databases.sql` and you have the patience for vi to load all 2GB of the file, I see no reason why this wouldn't work. So, +1 !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/CREATE DATABASE \/*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*\/ `mydb`/`mydb2`/g'
```

The first problem here is that this will replace every occurrence on any line of this:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `mydb`
```

with this:

```
`mydb2`
```

That's not what you want, because you still need the "CREATE DATABASE" at the beginning of the line.  Also, the database name will be used in at least one more place, that you also need to scrub, which is the `USE` that follows `CREATE DATABASE` in a `mysqldump` file that has more than one schema in it.

If `mydb` is a unique identifier that doesn't conflict with any other names in the file (such as a table or column also called `mydb` then you should be able to scrub it like so:

```
sed 's/`mydb`/`mydb2`/g'
```

If no joy there either, then the simplest approach is to divide up the file into three pieces -- the part before the database in question, the part after, and the part in the middle, where this database is.

Using grep, you can identify the line numbers of each `CREATE DATABASE` statement in the file, which you can use as split-points:

```
grep -n '^CREATE\ DATABASE' dumpfile.sql
```

Example output:

```
22:CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `accounting` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
173:CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `activity` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
2635:CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `auctions` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
```

In this case, the "activity" database is from line 173 through 2634 (the line prior to 2635 where the next database starts) in the file, so we can extract just those lines with sed.

```
sed -n '173,2634p' < originaldump.sql > activity.sql
```

Now you have a smaller and more manageable copy of just the "activity" database in a file by itself.